# Rails 4. Stack level too deep error when updating model in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

My problem is the following: When I try to update the model (`comment.rb`) in ActiveAdmin panel I get the `Stack level too deep` error.

Updating any other model works just fine in ActiveAdmin panel and when I delete or create new Comment, there're also no errors.

So, I tried to update my comment record in database through `rails console` using this command: `Comment.first.update_column :body, 'hello'` and it worked fine, but every time I try to update the record in ActiveAdmin panel, I get this infinite recursion and, to be honest, I can't even figure out what causes it.

Below are the parts of stacktrace of the error when I click the 'update' button in ActiveAdmin panel:

```
Started PATCH "/admin/product_comments/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-18 15:24:38 +0300
Processing by Admin::ProductCommentsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AhytIgM3DisFl4QZJaPL2JxFOC/3wKOawpeg6TT/GK3OyVUeotZ4whiQydKe/Jf4vLTsbrGicuiIr3ZfuQUC3Q==", "comment"=>{"user_id"=>"801", "product_id"=>"817", "body"=>"hello world!"}, "commit"=>"Update Comment", "id"=>"2"}
  AdminUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 801]]
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'user801@example.com' AND "users"."id" != 801) LIMIT 1
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 817]]
  Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."product_id" = $1  [["product_id", 817]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 801]]
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'user801@example.com' AND "users"."id" != 801) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'user801@example.com' AND "users"."id" != 801) LIMIT 1
```

and then the `User Exists` line repeats for a couple of billion times.

When `User Exists` lines end, there goes another piece of stacktrace:

```
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 198ms (ActiveRecord: 33.7ms)

SystemStackError - stack level too deep:
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/utils.rb:72:in `new'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/utils.rb:72:in `extract_schema_qualified_name'
  activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/quoting.rb:31:in `quote_table_name'
  arel (6.0.2) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:770:in `quote_table_name'
  arel (6.0.2) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:705:in `visit_Arel_Attributes_Attribute'
  arel (6.0.2) lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:13:in `visit'
  arel (6.0.2) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:669:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_Equality'
  arel (6.0.2) lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:13:in `visit'
```

and it also is about billion lines long.

Here's how my `Comment` model looks like:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product

  validates :body, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :user_id, :product_id, presence: true, numericality:
            { greater_than: 0, only_integer: true }
  validates_associated :user, :product

  # Method for displaying comment's id, user's full
  # name and product name in AdminPanel. ActiveAdmin
  # uses the `display_name` method in models for its
  # drop-down inputs.
  def display_name
    id.to_s + '. From: ' + user.first_name + ' ' +
      user.last_name + '. On: ' + product.name
  end
end
```

In `admin/comment.rb` I have the following:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Comment, as: "ProductComment" do
  # Yep, that's a lot of params, but I thought adding them would help :) 
  permit_params :id, :user_id, :product_id, :body, :user, :product

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :user
    column :product
    column :body
    actions
  end

  filter :user
  filter :product
  filter :created_at

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Edit Product Comment" do
      f.input :user
      f.input :product
      f.input :body
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

---

Could you please help me with figuring out what's going on here and how to resolve that issue?

PS: in case I haven't provided enough info, here're some links from my [repository](https://github.com/RubyBursaRelsohod/team_project/tree/71_dyakovenko):

1. [`app/admin` folder](https://github.com/RubyBursaRelsohod/team_project/tree/71_dyakovenko/app/admin)
2. [`product.rb` model](https://github.com/RubyBursaRelsohod/team_project/blob/71_dyakovenko/app/models/product.rb)
3. [`user.rb` model](https://github.com/RubyBursaRelsohod/team_project/blob/71_dyakovenko/app/models/user.rb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validates_associated` means you're also validating the user record when you save the comment record.

You have a validation on the User record where you specify that email must be unique but that validation (or some other validation in the User record) is flawed... as part of the validation you attempt to save the User record, but when saving the User record you're calling the validation, and as part of the validation you attempt to save the User record... doesn't end (until you run out of stack).

So check out your User validations.  To prove it's the problem,  you can temporarily remove the `validates_associated`

Comment: Yes, when I remove `validates_associated`, the error is gone. And I actually do have [some validations](http://pastebin.com/22ddRddZ) on User and there's the one on uniqueness of the email. 
So, it's just that the validations are somehow wrong? Or the `validates_associated` is redundant in `Comment`?

Comment: or maybe it is that the `User` that made the comment didn't pass the validation?

Comment: I'm not sure, you could try `User.find(108)` and then see if you can save it... or it could be that you have `validates_associated` in too many places, so comment validates user, which validates product ast part of it's validation, and validates product validates users as part of it's validation...